# Angular material no mat-error message

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an error with the material form validation, the mat-error message has never been displayed in the web page. Here is the code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="{{'DEPARTMENT' | translate}}"
         [FormControl]="inputDepartmentControl"
         [(ngModel)]="departmentValue"
         name="departmentValue"
         [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
         [matAutocomplete]="autoDepartment"
         (keyup)="onDepartmentChange()"
         (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)">
  <mat-error *ngIf="inputDepartmentControl.invalid">error</mat-error>
  <mat-autocomplete #autoDepartment="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let department of filteredDepartments | async" [value]="department.id">
      <span>{{department.id}} | </span>
      <span>{{department.value.name}}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <!--<mat-error *ngIf="(departmentInputControl)?.invalid">{{'DEPARTMENT_VALUE_ERROR' | translate}}</mat-error>-->
</mat-form-field>
```

The TS file, i have added this matcher class for a test:

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher{

  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched));
  }
}
```

The component class:

```
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
departmentValue = '';
inputDepartmentControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(3)]);
```

Every thing else works wee except the validation.

Can anyone tell me how to display the error message when the length of the string > 3?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not really a reproducable issue with the code you have presented, please share the minimal amount of code to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: As a sidenote, what I mean is that I see no error with the code you presented, and I tried it, worked fine, so error has to be somewhere in code that you are not showing.

Comment: So is there a problem that i use ngModel and formControl together? In the official exemple, there is juste FormControl.

Comment: Well yes, it's not good to mix them both. Could you create a demo that showcases this issue you are facing?